# How to post a json to my app ionic => symfony fosrestbundle

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, fosrestbundle, ngresource

I'm pretty new in angularJs, in my ionic
app I try to post 
a json to my app symfony fosrestbundle my app is correctly config.

but when I send my post the console
shows me this error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://127.0.01/gl/web/api/articles/5/comments . response for preflight has invalide status 405

I'm going crazy! does anyone have any
idea?!thanks a lot for the attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are you doing it?

First you need to bind the function to your html like this:

```
<button class="button button-energized" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
```

It's recomendded to use a service to do http calls, but you need to inject it (LoginService) in your controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService) {
 $scope.login = function() {
  LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.user, $scope.data.password)
     .then(function (data) {
      //grant access to the app
     });
 };
});
```

And in your service:

```
.factory('LoginService', function($http) {
    return {
     loginUser: function(user, password) {
         return $http.post('http://mydomain/login', {
               user: user,
               password: password
         });
     }
    };
```